# When I assign instance to a an elastic ip it's public-dns is changed

Tags: amazon-elastic-ip, amazon-web-services

Ok I have an instance (let's call it instance-1) with its public dns (let's call it
ec2-A-B-C-D.compute-1.amazonaws.com)
and another instance called instance-2 (public-dns : ec2-E-F-G-H)

I created an elastic ip (ip-50-X-Y-Z)

When I associate the elastic ip to the instance . The instance public dns changed to ec2-50-X-Y-Z which first of all I think it's weird.

Even weirder, If I deassociate instance-1 and associate instance-2 to my elastic-ip then :

instance-2 public dns changed to ec2-50-X-Y-Z) and instance-1 get a new public dns.

Since I am using usually using the public-dns to connect to my instance via ssh this is really messing up my ~/.ss/know_hosts file.

Is this the normal behavior of elastic ips or there is something messed up in my setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. When you request an elastic IP address, that IP address is fixed and you retain use of this IP until you relinquish it. If you assign it to any given instance, then the instance loses the IP it had (dynamic) and it is replaced with the elastic (fixed) ip address.

The idea is that the elastic IP address remains the same, so if you have a production site (with an FQDN mapped to this elastic IP address), then whenever you assign it to your server, you don't need to worry about any DNS changes.

Typically, you will have a number of elastic IP addresses, that you assign to your production, staging, test instances as required.

Comment: Ok but since I can only assigned 1 elastic ip to a given instance. I cannot use it to switch instance for maintenance purpose. (Well I can but this will cause mayhem in my know_hosts)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by mayhem - do you mean you no get prompted to add another host to the file. If this bothers you you could do something like: alias sshrelaxed="ssh -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no" . Then you can just run sshrelaxed user@server.address and the host will get added to /dev/null

Comment: I need to connect to instances using their public-dns (or public ip). If I switch instance for the elastic ip. The previously attached instance gets a new public dns and the newly attached instance gets the same public dns as the just detached instance. Which means the signature for that public dns changed and ssh refused to connect.

Comment: @barryj's comment will fix that.

Comment: Thank you for the ssh relaxed tip. I think I'm just disappointed because I thought public-dns were fixed and that I could swapped instance for a elastic ip without impacting the public ip of my instances.

Comment: So what is preventing you from doing this. Can you explain exactly what your problem is? Do you mean you don't know what address to connect to. It's either the initial IP/address, or the elastic IP/address, or another dynamic IP/address if you removed the elastic IP. You can determine the IP either from the console or via the API if you're trying to do it automatically.

Comment: OK I understand your issue now - I hadn't seen you last comment. As you state - there's only one public IP at a time, either elastic or dynamic.